# Is there a way to pre-load 1000's of images using SDWebImage into cache without actually showing them on screen?

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

I am using SDWebImage to download and cache images. I'd like to pre-load many of the images into cache.

Is there an easy way to do this without having to actually display the image to the user? I am currently using this code for displaying:

```
[anImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.sameple.com/myimage.jpg"] 
             placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loadingicon.png"]];
```

Comment: If your wanting to download 1000's of images I would suggest rolling your own method. I believe that SDWebImage will begin to purge at some point (can't look at docs atm).

Comment: I just want the images to be cached in exactly the same way as SDWebImage does (same name, etc). They have perfected their caching... anything I write may be prone to bugs they've already made fixes for.

Comment: Writing your own downloader with cache for a specific purpose is easy and straightforward. Writing a downloader and cache for the public to drop into project is hard. SDWebImage is very good but is in no way perfect. I would say that Path's FastImageCache is just as good as SDWebImage although i've never benchmarked the two.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
[[SDWebImagePrefetcher sharedImagePrefetcher] prefetchURLs:<NArray with image URLs>];
```

This will handle the concurrent download issue for you (`maxConcurrentDownloads`).

Comment: I'd mark this as the accepted answer. It requires the minimum amount of code and does exactly what the question asks

Answer (score 5):

> The SDWebImageManager is the class behind the UIImageView+WebCache
>   category. It ties the asynchronous downloader with the image cache
>   store. You can use this class directly to benefit from web image
>   downloading with caching in another context than a UIView (ie: with
>   Cocoa).

Here is a simple example of how to use SDWebImageManager:

```
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
[manager downloadWithURL:imageURL
                 options:0
                 progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize)
                 {
                     // progression tracking code
                 }
                 completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished)
                 {
                     if (image)
                     {
                         // do something with image
                     }
                 }];
```

You could run through and do this for every image...i'm not sure how the performance would be for 1000's of images and you will want to make sure and warn your user what your about to do.

Another approach sticking with `SDWebImage` would be to manage your own `NSOperationQueue` of `SDWebImageDownloaderOperation` and use this from `SDImageCache` to store them as they finish.

```
/**
 * Store an image into memory and optionally disk cache at the given key.
 *
 * @param image The image to store
 * @param key The unique image cache key, usually it's image absolute URL
 * @param toDisk Store the image to disk cache if YES
 */
- (void)storeImage:(UIImage *)image forKey:(NSString *)key toDisk:(BOOL)toDisk;
```

This would give you a little more control of how many concurrent download operations you had going as well as better state preservation control.

[Taken from GitHub page.](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Comment: Thanks! I was going to do them one-by-one in the background so I only have a single connection at a time... When one completes then I start the next one. I don't want to flood the background tasks.